# Passing `-std=c++11` to CMakeLists?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, cmake, compiler-flags

I have just installed Qt Creator and am using C++11 syntax.

Unfortunately when I try to build my project I get:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32: error:
      #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
             standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be
             enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
      #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
       ^
```

Then a bunch of errors like "`tuple` not a member of `std`".

My CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
project(routing_tests)
set(QMAKE_CXXFLAGS "-std=c++11")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

**EDIT: Tiny test case showing the issue https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8171073**

Comment: Show the cmake output, please along with your full CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Wait a minute QMake or CMake?

Comment: @drescherjm: exactly the point of my answer.

Comment: If CMake wouldn't it be set(CMAKE_CXXFLAGS "-std=c++11")

Comment: Ahh. My screen did not reflect you answer until just now..

Comment: @drescherjm: correct, see my project, http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=cutepaste.git&a=blob&h=fb4fd510b2a6453de9073853914018d4ad55ecc6&hb=a1201c7a1e83c0782cdef1b6247dc96d16523ffe&f=CMakeLists.txt#l25

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I added my full CMakeLists.txt to the question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    auto foo = std::make_tuple("bar", "foo", "can");
    std::cout << std::get<0>(foo) << std::get<1>(foo) << std::get<2>(foo);
}
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
project(tuple_tests)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
# C++14: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

Comment: Ah, so CMAKE rather than GMAKE.

Comment: @AT: you mean `QMAKE`, not `GMAKE`. You are the second person today making this typo. :)

Comment: @AT: you need to rerun cmake.

Comment: Ran `cmake` via command line, then `make`; and still got the errors.

Comment: @AT: that is about impossible. ;) Paste a main.cpp reproducing the issue. Also, check my project link above. How exactly do you rerun cmake?

Comment: Old version of gcc that does not support c++11? Would that ignore the parameter or error out?

Comment: @drescherjm: he has 4.8 based on the question which is good enough for tuple, et al. It is the latest major variant. `#if __cplusplus < 201103L` satisfies for the OP for some reason.

Comment: @AT: try to pass -std=c++0x. Does that work? Also, try "-std=gnu++11" for a moment. Try also `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`

Comment: Please try also `add_definitions("-std=c++11")`.

Comment: @AT: what does gcc --version return? Are you sure you do not have some obsolete version in the path? Have you tried each hint I gave you?

Comment: Your `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` one did the trick. I have edited your question with that solution + code example to show that it works. Accept my edit and I'll accept + up-vote your answer :)

Comment: Oh, I tried to edit it with the answer, you didn't accept my edits?

Comment: @AT: someone else rejected it, I am afraid, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3684662. I already exceeded my daily review quota about 10 hours ago, or so.

Comment: @AT I would accept this answer as the answer to the question instead of putting the answer in the question itself.

Comment: @drescherjm: I think AT just wanted to edit my answer, but it unfortunately got rejected. There is no problem though as the gist is pointed out, and the issue is resolved now.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Ahh, I see you reached your quota. No worries, I have committed the edit again for your review.

Comment: accoriding to: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html "You can use Clang in C++14 mode with the -std=c++14 option (use -std=c++1y in Clang 3.4 and earlier)."